# Phonegap/Cordova 1.8.0: ChildBrowser doesnt work onLocationChange

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Cordova 1.8.0 and an old version of Childbrowser (the new one doesnt seem to work).

Anyway, until yesterday night, this piece of code worked without any problem, this morning I clicked on run and the cb.onLocationChange stopped working.

I can't get how this is possible. Is there any one that can give me hints on that? onLocationChange doest return me any console.log :(

```
        var cb = ChildBrowser.install(); // install our ChildBrowser ( cb )
        console.log("AAAA We don't have a user saved yet");
        oauth = OAuth(options);
        oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            function(data) {
                console.log("AAAA Sent request token");
                requestParams = data.text;
                cb.showWebPage('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?'+data.text); // This opens the Twitter authorization / sign in page     
                console.log("AAAAAA onLocation chenge");
                cb.onLocationChange = function(loc){ console.log("AAAAAA"); Twitter.success(loc); }; // When the ChildBrowser URL changes we need to track that
            },
            function(data) { 
                console.log("ERROR: "+data);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question while I experiencing the same problem. The answer is here -
[Reference Error: Can't find variable: ChildBrowser, Cordova 1.7.0, jQueryMobile 1.0.1, iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864740/reference-error-cant-find-variable-childbrowser-cordova-1-7-0-jquerymobile)

The short answer in ChildBrowser.install() doesn't work anymore. Change your code's first line  to

```
cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
```